# xml tagged asp expression in head displays in body of the html page

Tags: xml, asp-classic

The following three lines, I presume are for building some data out of the database into an xml tree. The code sits in the head of the document, but in IE10 when it renders to the page, it renders *inside* the body. Only in IE10. Any ideas? I'm stumped!

```
<xml id="questionsXML">
<%=questionsXMLDOM.xml%>
</xml>
</head>
<%
// Open a database for use in drawing the body HTML
var db = OpenDatabase();
if (!db)
{
    Response.Write("Error opening database");
    Response.End();
}
var filtersQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM filters WITH (NOLOCK) "
+ "WHERE (report_id=" + SQLEncode(reportID) + " OR (report_id=0 AND                         test_battery_id=" + SQLEncode(tbid) + ") )"
        + "AND is_saved<>0 AND is_deleted=0 AND is_visible=1 "
        + "ORDER BY name ASC";
var filtersRS = db.Execute(filtersQuery);
%>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" scroll="no" onload="BodyOnLoad()"           style="background:#ffffff;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old HTML feature that Microsoft introduced called [XML data islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Microsoft has [removed support for this feature in Internet Explorer 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Their recommended short-term fix is to add an IE9 compatibility meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

The long-term fix is to remove the dependency on XML data islands. MDN has [one possible alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla).

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll check into removing the dependancy on data islands and try the meta tag in the short term. I have tried to encorporate the meta tag previously without success. Might have put it in the wrong file. Which file is the right one to put it in? I pulled this data from a default.asp file  ... Fingers crossed!

Comment: Cheran. Thank you! Tried attaching a query string on the end of the URL &viewdatasource=1. The version with IE9 returns an xml tree. IE10 returns a continuous string with no element formatting.